# Autoupdate Section Numbers? - Technical Document Authoring with Mathematica

Tags: data-structures, documentation

Technical document authoring systems are structured ways to create, manage, and update documentation for various mediums such as print, pdf, web, etc.

Take a look at this technical document ported to a mobile device/tablet:

[image: technicaldocument_on_tablet]
<sub>(source: [safetyawakenings.com](http://www.safetyawakenings.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/nfpa-101.jpg))</sub>

As you can see there is a structured format for the chapters and subsections in each chapter.

Chapter 1
1.1 First Section of Chapter 1
1.1.1 First Subsection of 1.1
1.1.2 Second Subsection of 1.1
1.2 Second Section of Chapter 1
1.2.1 First Subsection of 1.2

In this way, if the author were to add a new Section in the middle of a Chapter, all other numbers would need to be updated as it would disrupt the order.

For example, in the image above, imagine I inserted a new Section, called "General 2", under the "7.1 General" section. 

Then "7.2 Means of Egress Components" would need to become 7.3 instead of 7.2, and so on.

I am hoping there is a straightforward way mathematica can auto-update section numbers in a technical document, as in the above scenario, so that it is a viable solution for technical authoring.

Comment: If you use the Section/Subsection... styling, numbers will update automatically. The thing you need to do in referencing the sections is make sure to use Insert>Automatic Numbering.